# Will pixel shader cut some points? (I want to generate voxel)

Tags: directx, render, hlsl

I have to save every vertex for generating voxel. No culling back, the whole scene can be store to voxel, but I don't know how to pass the pixel shader if the vertex is lost. Should I put camera to far place for that whole scene can be show? Transfrom position to world coordinate, and save the color? please!

Comment: add： About RWTexture<type>   ,If I  read the Rw,the type must be 32bit?

Comment: What you are looking for is called conservative rasterization, It can be as easy as turning a flag in D3D12 with a compatible hardware, or involve math and geometry expansion if not to make sure any touched pixel by the triangle is really generating a value.

Comment: My hardware doesn't support D3D12. But I read that the next step of pixel shader  is depth test .Does it mean no vertex is lost ?